# Script in batch Cisco

Tags: batch-file, cisco, cisco-ios

It is possible to create a script, which will copy and save configuration from Cisco device?

I have already created this in a batch file:

```
C:\putty.exe -ssh XX.XX.XX.XX -l XXXXXX -pw XXXXXX
```

So I can successfully login to `SW`. But, if I write any other command after that in the batch file, it doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to make it work? For example:

send "configure terminal" or something like this..

Comment: is `putty`s switch `/m` helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you used (putty.exe -ssh) opens a session to a server. While in this session, you can execute any command and the moment you leave the session (CTLR + C most commonly) your batch script continues to execute.

Structure is something like this:

- Batch starts

  - SSH Session starts and ends
- Batch script continues

What you **can** do is calling the SSH function with a parameter something like:

```
C:\putty.exe -ssh HOST -l USER -pw PASSWORD -m "YOURCOMMAND"
```

For more information look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running).

**OR:** You use a script you will call from the switch (remote ressource)

**OR:** You create a [CISCO API script](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/2-x/rest_cfg/2_1_x/b_Cisco_APIC_REST_API_Configuration_Guide.html)

Comment: Realy thanks for quick answer and help, I have already added -m "C:\command.txt", and into txt file I wrote command to copy running config and it is working properly

but now there is next problem, because I need to hit ENTER button. I found this:

read -n 1 -s -r -p "Address or name of remote host [10.1.1.1]? " , but command line still waiting for enter

Thanks

Comment: Look for a quiet (-q?) or a confirmation (-y?) option in the command options

Comment: Hello, I need only press ENTER in that script.

Comment: Then adjust it so it is a quiet command (-q?) or an preconfirmed command (most likely -y) so it will not ask you for confirmation anymore...

Comment: okay, could you please send me example of script configuration, so where to use -q or -y ? thank you

Comment: You need to look this up for the specific command causing the break. If you send me this command I may be able to look it up...